# How to run a command without cancelling visual selection in vim

Tags: vim

In vim, lets say i do: `viw` (start visual mode and select the current word)

I then do `:echo "abc"` (I may have to erase the range specification, which is added automatically when typing `:` in visual mode)

Running the echo command  cancels the visual selection. 
How can I maintain the visual selection, even after I executed the echo command?

Comment: (the purpose is that I would like to be able to `vmap` a keybinding which remembers the column index of the last selected character by doing `:let lastSelectedCharacterIndex = virtcol("'>")`. However, I still want to do other things with the same visual selection (after having remembered the `lastSelectedCharacterIndex`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The visual selection is inevitably lost when you've entered command-line mode (for the `:echo`), but Vim remembers the selection mode, start and end positions in the [`'<`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#%27%3C) and `'>` marks. The `gv` command lets you quickly reselect the previous selection; cp. [`:help reselect-Visual`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/visual.txt.html#reselect-Visual).

Some people like to have the selection persist (e.g. for shifting lines via `<` and `>`), and configure this via custom mappings that append `gv` to the original commands.

For your stated use case of generic Ex commands, I don't think that makes sense, though. If you're just briefly breaking out of visual mode in a mapping (as you've clarified in a comment), `gv` is exactly right. Alternatively, you could avoid leaving visual mode via a [`:help :map-expression`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#%3Amap-expression), do the stuff as a side effect, and then return an empty string, so nothing gets executed. However, as you need to store the visual end column, visual mode needs to be concluded for the `'>` mark to be updated, so that wouldn't work here; you actually have to leave visual mode temporarily.

Comment: Thanks! `gv` accomplished exactly the thing I was looking for, because I needed this functionality only in one specific keymapping.